# Change the headlines of a attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, table, column, heading

I would like to change the heading of a column in the attribute table of QGIS.
Originally I had a vector layer linked to an Excel table and so now I have old and new forest locations.

But both columns currently still have the same name. I want to name one "old forest loc" and the other one "new forest loc".

Actually this should be totally easy but I just can't figure out what I have to do.

Comment: Look for the processing tool "Refactor fields" : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields

Comment: @BERA I considered suggesting this but both old fields are called the same so its hard to specify what field you want

Comment: Do they have the same name exactly? sometimes QGIS will append a "_1" if a field name exists

Comment: They cant have the same name, maybe OP is meaning the field alias

Comment: one of the two columns has a "_1". does that change my options?
however, both columns have over 1000 lines each. so a new column and then typing in does not work.
is there a way to "copy" a whole column? then i could create a new column and "paste" the data from the old column. or how could i do this with the field calculator? i have not found the right expression yet.

Comment: the option with the "refactor fields" I will try right away thanks!

Comment: Field calculator will do the "copying" for you

Answer (score 3):

It's not intuitive and I couldn't find it in the manual either. But I've found this works to rename a column in the attribute table if you need to.

- Right click on the layer.
- Go to properties.
- Go to `Fields` in the menu column on the left-hand side.
- Click the pencil icon at the top to initiate an edit: [image: pencil icon]
- Every field of your layer is listed as a row. Double click on the "Name" of the one you want to change, then type in the new
  name.
- Click `OK`.
- Save layer edits as you would save any other edit: [image: save icon]